# In android test, when use intent open another app, how to return to my app and continue later tests

Tags: java, android

For ex:

```
@Test
public void useAppContext() {
    ActivityTestRule rule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class, false, false);
    final MainActivity act = (MainActivity) rule.launchActivity(new Intent());
    act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://example.com"));
            act.startActivity(intent);
            // I wanna return to my app and do other tests
        }
    });
}
```

I hope return to my app and continue do other things, how should i do?

Comment: I think you need UIAutomator. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator

Answer (score 0):

> I hope return to my app and continue do other things, how should i do?

**The short answer:**

[Espresso.pressBackUnconditionally()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/Espresso.html?hl=en#pressbackunconditionally) or [UiDevice.pressBack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html?hl=en#pressback)

**The long answer:**

You shouldn't :)

You are explicitly launching an Intent as part of your test but you shouldn't. Your test should not be executing logic - your test should be driving your code to cause *your actual code* to execute logic. A UI test should look more like:

```
// Click a button on screen that navigates to new URL
onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click()) 
intended(hasData("https://example.com"))
```

Secondly, your tests should be small and targeted. Think in "assemble, act, assert" terms where you set up a test, do something to trigger an expectation, and then assert *one expectation*.

So instead of a launching a new activity, then coming back, and doing more assertions all as part of one test, you should break it up into multiple tests. One test verifies the URL opens. A separate test could start in the state you would be in after pressing back on the opened Activity, and continuing from there.

This strategy makes your tests more reliable and predictable.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Intents not initialized. Did you forget to call init()?